# Ant Design for react native truly native components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, antd

I am building a application using react native and am wanting to keep the components as native as possible.
[Ant Design](https://mobile.ant.design/) looks really good but i am worried that the components are not native and just web components? They state "Right now we include 47 web components and 40 native components."

Basically my question is has any one worked with this library ? What was the performance like with these designs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "as native as possible" as far as I know, all ends with .native.tsx, are react native components. if you want truely "native" you should use Java/swift maybe?

Answer (score 13):

You have to understand that right now there are 3 versions of **ant-design**

- [antd](https://ant.design/): Which is for web projects.
- [antd-mobile](https://mobile.ant.design/): Which is for web mobile projects.
- [antd-mobile-rn](https://rn.mobile.ant.design/): Which is for native mobile projects.

And you should also check out **Marc Lore** answer of **How does react native work** question http://qr.ae/TUIrTu.

With that in mind right now as far as I now there are a lot of Framework UIs for react native, but none of them are truly NATIVE, those are just components that would run on the Javascript Thread, but don't underestimate them, because they are very fast, and customizable; The only native solutions for react-native are some Calendars, Popups, and [Navigators](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/thousand-ways-to-navigate-in-react-native-f7a1e311a0e8).

Ant design it's very awesome, and there are a lot of people backing the project up so it's an active project, I've been working on some private projects for the company I work for, using ant-design, and we haven't had any performance issues, take into account that performance it's also measured for a lot of factors, like if you are using too much observables (redux and rxjs/sagas), overenginnering the layouts, available RAM on the device etc.

A little late for an answer but I hope you give it a chance :D.

**Note:** I'll keep updating this answer when I find some TRULY NATIVE components for react-native.

Comment: I'm planning to make an app which can work with mobile(Android & iOS) and Web platform using single code that can run and give same/similar output using ant design. Is it possible with ant design?

Comment: @AshvinAjadiya well is not 100% code reusing, but you can have a 60% - 80%, it depends in how you structure your code.